# How to pass argument that implements a interface?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I have a interface:

```
public interface InterfaceX {
    void methodX();
}
```

A class that have a method to receive a object that implements that interface:

```
public class AClass {
    public <T extends InterfaceX>  void Method( Class<T> argument ) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

And a class that implements the interface and wants to call the above method..

```
public class BClass implements InterfaceX {
    @Override
    public void methodX() {
    }

    public void callAClassMethod() {
        AClass aClass = new AClass();
        aClass.Method(this);
    }
}
```

How to do this? In this code I have the error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that BClass conforms to Class<T>

Comment: If I'm correct, the return type is VOID. If you prefer: public  void Method2( Class<? extends AClass> argument ), don't works also.

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to markspace, I found the solution:

```
public class AClass {
    private List<? extends InterfaceX> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    public <T extends InterfaceX>  void Method( T argument ) {
         myList.add(argument); // error here now... !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. One question, that gets answers. The idea is not to come back with other problems in answers or comments. This isn't a free tutoring service where people sit down with you and work with you through all aspects of your homework.

Comment: And beyond that, be careful about asking others your first strategy. Learning programming is also about learning how to solve problems completely yourself. You should first spent hours trying to do that, and only when tried 5 or 10 things yourself and you are still lost, then ask others.

Comment: No worries, just remember it, and focus on trying yourself first, and waiting with questions a bit in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Didn't test this, but if you want the class type, you have to call `getClass()`.

```
public class BClass implements InterfaceX {
    @Override
    public void methodX() {
    }

    public void callAClassMethod() {
        AClass aClass = new AClass();
        aClass.Method(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to pass a class instance, not the class. In fact with your answer show me what are wrong. Voted UP.